# Top level domain/domain suffix for private network?

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network, hostname, best-practices

At our office, we have a local area network with a purely internal DNS setup, on which clients all named as `whatever.lan`.  I also have a VMware environment, and on the virtual-machine-only network, I name the virtual machines `whatever.vm`.

Currently, this network for the virtual machines isn't reachable from our local area network, but we're setting up a production network to migrate these virtual machines to, which *will* be reachable from the LAN.  As a result, we're trying to settle on a convention for the domain suffix/TLD we apply to the guests on this new network we're setting up, but we can't come up with a good one, given that `.vm`, `.local` and `.lan` all have existing connotations in our environment.

So, what's the best practice in this situation?  Is there a list of TLDs or domain names somewhere that's safe to use for a purely internal network?

Comment: Don't use .local. Especially if you've got any Apple clients.

Comment: .test is set aside for this reason: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/.test

Comment: @CWSpear That's not the actual *reason* `.test` is reserved, though it does make it a safe domain to use for ***test*** networks that won't be connected to the internet.

Comment: @Otto best practices would dictate that you acquire a "real" domain name (under an ICANN-recognized TLD) and create a subdomain of that for your local stuff (e.g. register `mydomain.com`, delegate `internal.mydomain.com` to an internal NS, and properly configure split horizon DNS ("views" in BIND) so you don't leak internal names/addresses to the internet.  It's not as pretty as a TLD/pseudo-TLD, but it's less prone to breakage as it's under your control.

Comment: **However**: don't use a real domain name that you have already used for public-facing production services. There are various interactions that are allowed between `www.example.com` and `*.internal.example.com` that are not allowed between `www.example.com` and `*.example.net`, most notably cross-site cookie setting. Running internal and external services on the same domain increases the risk that a compromise of a public service will give some ingress to the internal services, and conversely that an insecure internal service could provoke internal misuse of an external service.

Comment: .local is officially reserved for MDNS on internal networks.   See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762.   So using it will be horribly slow, it will have to wait to timeout.

Comment: Make it start with a letter. Someone I know used a TLD that starts with a number, then had trouble with several softwares that rejected it as invalid.

Comment: @simlev while technically it could work, the current regulations and specifically ICANN ones, forbid digits in TLDs, except for IDN TLDs which have the form `xn--something`. See my longer answer I just posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875771/6368697

Comment: What's wrong with using `-local`/`-lan` instead of `.local`/`.lan` though? Is it really important to have a dot in your hostname, other than Firefox's annoying behaviour of trying to resolve a google query as a DNS lookup finally have a true positive?

Comment: Using an invented TLD has countless problems, and there's no reason for it. Use a subdomain of your main domain (corp.company.com) or your main domain (company.com).

In some cases, I've even counseled organizations to buy a second domain for purely infrastructure, if they wanted to set up DNS for all internal hosts. They used example.com for all their external facing services and all their internal infrastructure had DNS records in the examplecorp.com.

They didn't miss the $12 a year, and neither will you.

Comment: Please consider support by browser when write .local,.lan,..etc not show as search should shown as domain ,by testing both brave,firefox dev the supported was **.test**,**.example** that not gonna redirect it search engine

Comment: Since 2018 there actually is a suffix defined for local/home use: `*.home.arpa`. It's not pretty, but at least it's standardized (RFC 8375).

Comment: @bobince: I found in your statement that `*.internal.example.com` is under `*.example.com`, does not? Thus communication should not be allowed between them.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Since the previous answers to this question were written, there have been a couple of RFCs that alter the guidance somewhat.  [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) discusses special-use domain names without providing specific guidance for private networks.  [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) still recommends not using unregistered TLDs, but also acknowledges that there are cases where it will be done anyway.  Since the commonly used **.local** conflicts with Multicast DNS (the main topic of the RFC), [Appendix G.  Private DNS Namespaces](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#appendix-G) recommends the following TLDs:

- intranet
- internal
- private
- corp
- home
- lan

IANA appears to [recognize both RFCs](https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml) but does not (currently) incorporate the names listed in Appendix G.

In other words: you shouldn't do it.  But when you decide to do it anyway, use one of the above names.

Update 1/2024: We're getting closer to having some definitive guidance on this.  IANA has made a provisional determination that ICANN has opened up for [public comment](https://www.icann.org/en/public-comment/proceeding/proposed-top-level-domain-string-for-private-use-24-01-2024) (the recommendation is to use **.internal**)

Comment: The Appendix G has before the list you quote: "We do not recommend use of unregistered top-level domains at all". This is more the key point. The names given are not "recommended" to use, they are just observed names seen that will work better than `.local` which is kind of reserved for MulticastDNS, which is the discussion in Appendix G.

Comment: I would disagree.  The key point is the absurdity of the advice: 'don't do it... but when you do...'  The expectation that home/small business/non-publicly facing networks should register a TLD is not realistic.  People **are** going to use unregistered TLDs so far better to help everyone out and say 'OK, here's a list of unregistered TLDs you can use internally' rather than pretending everyone is going to follow the hard line advice.

Comment: We will remain in disagreement then. The fact that some people used TLD like they are internal (for example `.MAIL`  found in many documentations) is exactly the reason why these TLDs were not possible to delegate and are now indefinitely dead. Hence continuing to recommend to people to use TLDs in that way is a disservice to the global Internet community. The advice says that since some TLDs are already abused like that, if people have to abuse they should reuse those one instead of abusing new ones. RFC2606 is clear for the TLDs to use internally that will work: `.EXAMPLE` `.TEST` `.INVALID`

Comment: `home.arpa.` from [RFC8375](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8375) is now reserved on [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml).

Comment: Somehow I had missed this response, I feel like this is the most useful overall. I get that folks shouldn't do it (I haven't been since I asked the question, originally) but now there's an RFC I can point at that explains why but also happens to set aside some that aren't likely to be reserved by a different RFC.

Comment: I just stumbled upon [SAC113: SSAC Advisory on Private-Use TLDs](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/sac-113-en.pdf), in which an ICANN committee recommends that ICANN establish some TLD for private use networks (but doesn't recommend any particular string).

Comment: Since 2018 there actually is a suffix defined for local/home use: `*.home.arpa`. It's not pretty, but at least it's standardized (RFC 8375).

Answer (score 114):

Do not use an invented TLD. If ICANN were to delegate it, you would be in big trouble. Same thing if you merge with another organization which happens to use the same dummy TLD. That's why globally unique domain names are preferred.

The standard, [RFC 2606](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt) reserves names for examples, documentation, testing, but nothing for general use, and for good reasons: today, it is so easy and cheap to get a real and unique domain name that there is no good reason to use a dummy one.

So, buy `iamthebest.org` and use it to name your devices.

Comment: To be totally secure I would put everything on a subdomain of my company's domain name, like local.company.org, vm.company.org, and so on.

Comment: +1 this. Presumably your company already has a domain. Just create a sub-domain from this. It doesn't have to be visible/resolvable outside of your LAN.

Comment: This is good advice. We ran a few different made up domains, then switched to a unified int.abbrev, but with some of ICANN's rules, that could theoretically become a viable domain, which could really screw us if we needed to communicate with it. It's not a country code, otherwise I would have bought it already.

Comment: In the rare case that ICANN delegates our TLD, and the even more rare case that we could not register the domain under that TLD, then we would simply follow the ICANN's UDRP procedures to protect our trademark.

Additionally, since this is internal only it would not affect us in anyway if the domain was publicly registered other than not being able to access this public domain through our internal DNS servers.

This assumes that you are not simply using host.TLD, but instead host.domain.TLD where "domain" is a registered trademark.

Comment: Well, even with very good lawyers, you will have trouble claiming ".lan" or ".local" by invoking a trademark. And the argument "it is internal only" is extremely weak: organizations merge, set up virtual private networks with partner organizations and simply make mistakes such that "private" names leak.

Comment: My only beef with this is that you can't really "buy" a domain: you can only rent one. Some bozo forgets to pay a bill (and this has happened in a few high-profile cases) and a core part of your configuration goes to some random squatter. So you use your company's domain? Execs decide to rebrand or get bought out, and you're stuck with an old name. .local used to work well enough, but it's now been preempted by a certain company in ways that refuse to play nice. I'd really like so see something like .lan or .internal formally reserved for this purpose, but until then this is the best option.

Comment: Agree with @Joel Coel, you are a renter, and nothing more.  There should be two reserved TLD names *for internal use only* that should be considered invalid in public and not reachable by public networks.  One name would be for internal home use, the second name would be for internal business use.  Both would be considered "private TLDs" in the same sense that we have "private subnets" that are non-routable (192.168.x.x and ilk).  This allows home users to do something besides being forced into .local and mDNS.  Ditto for small businesses running an internal LAN behind a NAT with no domain.

Comment: @AveryPayne FWIW, `.example`, `.test`, and `.invalid` are reserved... but those are hardly good semantic choices, either.

Comment: From The Register - [Do you use .home and .mail on your network? ICANN mulls .corp, .mail, .home dot-word domains](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/03/13/icann_gtlds_corp_home_mail/)
*'High risk' gTLDs pondered by money-loving DNS overseer*

Comment: `home.arpa.` from [RFC8375](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8375) is now reserved on [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml). So you can use it (or a subdomain of it) on your private network.

Comment: given how this value proliferates, and often directly for human entry, I have a strong preference towards something short, memorable, and hard-to mis-enter

Comment: It's a ridiculous notion that the use of domain names is exclusively limit to those with funds to maintain a registered domain. While most registrars aren't that expensive, it's becoming increasingly difficult to not end up with "my-new-project-idea.com" which is absolutely lovely to type. Frankly the level of domain squating and limited value beyond the initial public gold rush is much worse that the ipv4 situation

Comment: My Indonesian friend has just reported that test.lan is resolves by her ISP :))

Comment: I need to short-term test some web apps locally on my network by myself and a couple others.  I assume the .test TLD is fine for this.

Answer (score 61):

Use a subdomain of your company's registered domain for internal machines whose names you do not want available on the Internet.  (Then, of course, only host those names on your internal DNS servers.)  Here are some examples for the fictitious Example Corporation.

**Internet-facing servers:**
www.example.com
mail.example.com
dns1.example.com

**Internal machines:**
dc1.corp.example.com
dns1.corp.example.com
client1.corp.example.com

I used "corp" to signify that this subdomain described machines on the internal corporate network, but you could use anything you want here, such as "internal":  client1.internal.example.com.

Remember, too, that DNS zones and subdomains do not have to align with your network numbering scheme.  My company, for example, has 37 locations, each with its own subnet, but all locations use the same (internal) domain name.  Conversely, you could have only one or a few subnets, but many peer internal domains or levels of subdomains to help you organize your machines.

Comment: @bobince explained in another comment how this can lead to problems: https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network#comment782543_17255

Answer (score 36):

There's another advantage of using an internal subdomain: cleverly using search suffixes and only hostnames instead of FQDN, you can build configuration files that work both in development, QA and production.

For example, you always use "database = dbserv1" in your configuration file.

On the development server, you set the search suffix to "dev.example.com"
=> database server used: dbserv1.dev.example.com

On the QA server, you set the search suffix to "qa.example.com" 
=> database server used: dbserv1.qa.example.com

And on the production server, you set the search suffix to "example.com" 
=> database server used: dbserv1.example.com

That way, you can use the same settings in every environment.

Comment: That is brilliant.

Comment: Until someone mis-configs their workstation with the production search suffix to test an issue, and later inadvertently updates a bunch of production records.

Comment: That is pretty crude, SRV records are very simple to parse and can be placed within any zone, such that the same db server serves several zones. In this case some bit of code would be filling in the value within your config files. And you can use the name of the database as the SRV key and the value of course pointing to the hostname. I'd never rely on search suffixes. You can also get quite creative with TXT records, and can stuff them with aes-256 encrypted (then base64 encoded) values, if they're secrets. You can use TXT records for all sorts of things.

Comment: see, but what I want is example.com, example.dev, and example.stg. The last 2 are only on a private network, can I setup a local DNS server for zero config access? Still using a similar config here for all sites, just moving changes up to tld. Easy for .dev with a hosts file, but zero config...

Comment: formatting/populating a config file should _not_ be the bottleneck for promoting code

Comment: @JoelCoel I would certainly hope your dev, QA, and prod databases have different credentials.

Comment: @ndm13 Certificate auth, where the someone in question has both certificates available

Comment: Please never do this. It is one of those "smart" things you realize you *can* do after the first time you read the "BIND & DNS" O'Reilly book. But the **pain** of troubleshooting / tracking down the handful of systems that happens to use some hardcoded FQDN hostname *or* are manually misconfigured using the wrong (i.e. prod instead of qa) such search suffix is going to outweigh **all** the convenience gained.

Answer (score 36):

As always there are de jure and de facto standards.

While "nonprofit" ICANN plays in politics and money we, common people, suffer. IETF once introduced `.home` (RFC 7788) for personal home intranets but they don't have power over only-for-pofit IANA players and reintroduced domain under `.home.arpa` (RFC 8375) as IETF controls only `.arpa`.

Appendix G of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762 mentions:

```
.intranet .internal .private .corp .home .lan
```

for use if you **really want** internal TLD.

Big players (Google, Amazon) use `.internal` for virtual intranets:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html - A private (internal) DNS hostname resolves to the private IPv4 address of the instance. The
  private DNS hostname takes the form `ip-private-ipv4-address.ec2.internal` for the `us-east-1`
  Region, and `ip-private-ipv4-address.region.compute.internal` for other Regions (where
  private-ipv4-address is the reverse lookup IP address).
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns
  Zonal DNS `[INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal` for all organizations or standalone
  projects that have enabled the Compute Engine API after September 06, 2018.

Those companies can buy the Internet. So it is de facto safe to use `.internal` TLD internally ))

Comment: This is a good answer because it covers both what is technically best according to specifications and what is safe from a practical standpoint.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I think "those companies can buy the Internet. So it is de facto safe to use .internal TLD internally" is the key insight. Google and Amazon would refactor the Internet if that meant they can avoid hitting a minor snag in their own infrastructure. They are all-powerful.

Comment: the fact that .local is used by both Apple and Microsoft makes it just unlikely that ICANN would delegate .local as .internal, imo

Comment: This is a real answer.  The rest of the "don't do it" advice make wild assumptions about your use cases.   No, I don't want to rent the name of my internal domain from icann who can hand it to a squatter or someone with deeper lawsuit pockets and a clever lawyer.  No thanks.

Answer (score 13):

As already said, you should not use an unregistered TLD for your private network. Especially now that ICANN allows almost anybody to register new TLDs.
You should then use a real domain name.

On the other side, the [RFC 1918](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt) is clear:

> Indirect references to such addresses should be contained within the enterprise.
>   Prominent examples of such references are DNS Resource Records and other  information referring to internal private addresses.

So your name server should also use views to prevent the private records to be transmitted on the Internet.

Comment: Registering your own TLD is typically not an option for anyone except rather large organisations because of the price.  Definitely not for home users.

Comment: @GöranUddeborg: You misunderstand the answer. The answer does not recommend that you should register your own TLD, it just warns that new TLDs _could be created_ which might conflict with the TLD you chose. The advice is to just register your own domain name (which is cheap).

Comment: .internal and .local are both defacto locked-up by companies for internal use.

Answer (score 11):

We tend to consider no difference in the virtual naming of hosts from the physical - in fact, we've taken to abstracting the host configuration (software) from the physical layer.

So we purchase Hardware Items, and create Host Items on top of them (and use a simple relationship to show that in our documentation).

The purpose is that when a host exists, DNS shouldn't be the determining factor - as we've have machines move from one space to the next - for instance a low-performing webapp has no need to consume expensive CPU cycles - virtualize it, and it retains its naming scheme, everything continues to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a useful question and the answers here are really helpful. I've gathered the main considerations as I see them:

- [It's not a good idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network#comment782543_17255) to use subdomains of a publicly facing domain.
- [Amazon.com and Google use](https://serverfault.com/a/1041148) `.internal`.
- [RFC 6762 Appendix G says](https://serverfault.com/a/937808) that a lot of people use `.internal`, saying (paraphrased), "don't use a custom TLD, but if you do, we've seen a few in use, including `.internal`".
- [SAC113: SSAC Advisory on Private-Use TLDs](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/sac-113-en.pdf) says ICANN should really come up with a TLD for private networks. It uses `.internal` as a hypothetical example (while protesting that it is not actually *recommending* `.internal`). In the graph of real-world queries it shows `.internal` as one of the most popular, and SAC113 singles it out (along with `.home` and `.lan`) as examples.

Understanding that the best practice would seem to be to purchase a separate domain, but taking the above items into consideration, as of 2023 I have decided to go with `.internal`. I have not read any *realistic* possible scenarios that would cause problems in practice.

Answer (score 2):

An expired Internet Draft entitled [Top-level Domains for Private Internets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dnsop-private-use-tld) would have sanctioned the use of the 42 two-letter "user assigned code elements" as TLDs for private use.

- `AA`
- `QM` to `QZ`
- `XA` to `XZ`
- `ZZ`

So we could have used

- [`aaaaaa.aaaaaaaaaa.aa`](https://en.uncyclopedia.co/wiki/AAAAAAAAA!)
- `gg.qq`
- `tired.zz`
- `windows.xp`

and so on.

While this draft has expired, and therefore won't become a proposed standard, at IETF-111 the [dnsop](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/111/proceedings#dnsop) group had an update on the proposal: [minutes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/111/materials/minutes-111-dnsop-00) [video](https://youtu.be/uoDVpNSdt7E?t=1025) [slides1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/111/materials/slides-111-dnsop-sessb-liaison-reply-iso-3166-1-user-defined-codes-for-private-use-tld-00) [slides2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/111/materials/slides-111-dnsop-sessb-private-tld-next-steps-00)

The update ends with (emphasis my own):

> Change the approach of the draft as follows:
>
> - Recognize that **User Assigned 3166 code elements are used in various ways,
>   including private networks**
> - Recognize that these elements have not been delegated and are **known to be
>   used by some people to anchor private namespaces**
> - Do not recommend anything, do not reserve anything, no registries
> - Do not promote any particular interpretation of the current standards
> - Document **potential future pitfalls** for using these codes for private namespaces
> - **Empower readers to make their own decisions**

So, reading between the lines, and in the spirit of permissionless innovation...

But seriously, watch the video or at least read the minutes before using any of these!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding [RFC 8375 - Special-Use Domain 'home.arpa.'](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375), below is a `hosts` file showcasing a simple residential/office network setup. Up to line 23, it is exactly the same as Windows 11. `home.arpa.` is excluded from the Global DNS System and is therefore the safest option **for those not renting a domain name**.

Comments include relevant portions of:

[RFC952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) - **DOD INTERNET HOST TABLE SPECIFICATION**

[RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) - **Requirements for Internet Hosts - Application and Support**

[RFC6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) - **Multicast DNS**

[RFC8375](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375) - **Special-Use Domain `home.arpa.`**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.lan          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.lan              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RFC 952 and RFC 1123 Hosts File
# https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952
# https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123
# 
# This file contains hostname to IP address mappings for TCP/IP networks.
# 
# RFC 952 and RFC 1123 are standards that define the rules for hostnames in 
# the Internet. According to these standards, a compliant hostname must 
# meet the following criteria:
# 
# It can contain letters (A-Z, a-z), digits (0-9), hyphens (-), and periods (.).
# It must start with an alphanumeric character (letter or digit) and end 
# with an alphanumeric character.
# Hyphens (-) can be used as a separator but must not be at the beginning 
# or end of a label (part of the hostname separated by periods).
# Periods (.) are used to separate labels, which usually represent
# different levels of the domain hierarchy.
# Hostnames are case-insensitive.
# 
# RFC 1123 updated the original hostname requirements in RFC 952 to allow
# hostnames to start with digits. However, it did not change the maximum
# hostname length. The maximum length of a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
# is 253 characters (excluding the trailing dot). This limit is based on the
# maximum size of a DNS message, which is 512 bytes, and the requirement to
# accommodate other data fields within the DNS message, such as the query
# type and class.
# 
# The format for entries in a hosts file is <IP-address> <hostname> <alias(es)>
# 
# RFC 6762 - Multicast DNS
# https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762
# https://serverfault.com/a/1041148
# 
# Appendix G. Private DNS Namespaces
# 
# The special treatment of names ending in ".local." has been
# implemented in Macintosh computers since the days of Mac OS 9, and
# continues today in Mac OS X and iOS. There are also implementations
# for Microsoft Windows [B4W], Linux, and other platforms.
# 
# Some network operators setting up private internal networks
# ("intranets") have used unregistered top-level domains, and some may
# have used the ".local" top-level domain. Using ".local" as a private
# top-level domain conflicts with Multicast DNS and may cause problems
# for users. Clients can be configured to send both Multicast and
# Unicast DNS queries in parallel for these names, and this does allow
# names to be looked up both ways, but this results in additional
# network traffic and additional delays in name resolution, as well as
# potentially creating user confusion when it is not clear whether any
# given result was received via link-local multicast from a peer on the
# same link, or from the configured unicast name server. Because of
# this, we recommend against using ".local" as a private Unicast DNS
# top-level domain. We do not recommend use of unregistered top-level
# domains at all, but should network operators decide to do this, the
# following top-level domains have been used on private internal
# networks without the problems caused by trying to reuse ".local." for
# this purpose:
# 
#     .intranet.
#     .internal. (Google, Amazon) virtual intranets
#     .private.
#     .corp.
#     .home.
#     .lan.
# 
# RFC 8375 - Special-Use Domain 'home.arpa.'
# https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375
# 
# 3.  General Guidance
# 
# The domain name 'home.arpa.' is to be used for naming within
# residential homenets. Names ending with '.home.arpa.' reference a
# zone that is served locally, the contents of which are unique only to
# a particular homenet and are not globally unique. Such names refer
# to nodes and/or services that are located within a homenet (e.g., a
# printer or a toaster).
# 
# DNS queries for names ending with '.home.arpa.' are resolved using
# local resolvers on the homenet. Such queries MUST NOT be recursively
# forwarded to servers outside the logical boundaries of the homenet.
# 
# Some service discovery user interfaces that are expected to be used
# on homenets conceal information such as domain names from end users.
# However, in some cases, it is still expected that users will need to
# see, remember, and even type names ending with '.home.arpa.'. The
# Homenet Working Group hopes that this name will in some way indicate
# to as many readers as possible that such domain names are referring
# to devices in the home, but we recognize that it is an imperfect
# solution.
# 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

# loopback address
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

# RFC 952-compliant host entries using RFC 8375 Special-Use Domain 'home.arpa.'

# [IPv4]        DNS server                [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.2        dnsserver1.home.arpa      dns.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        DHCP server               [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.3        dhcpserver1.home.arpa     dhcp.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Proxy server              [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.4        proxyserver1.home.arpa    proxy.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Web server                [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.5        webserver1.home.arpa      www.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        File server               [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.6        fileserver1.home.arpa     files.home.arpa sftp.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Application server        [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.7        appserver1.home.arpa      app.home.arpa api.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Database server           [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.8        dbserver1.home.arpa       db.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Mail server               [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.9        mailserver1.home.arpa     smtp.home.arpa imap.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Print server              [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.10       printer1.home.arpa        printer.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Backup server             [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.11       backupserver1.home.arpa   backup.home.arpa

# [IPv4]        Remote Desktop Services   [Alias(es)]
10.0.0.12       rds1.home.arpa            rds.home.arpa

# end of file
```

Answer (score 2):

As of late January 2024, ICANN is officially proposing .INTERNAL:

[Proposed Top-Level Domain String for Private Use](https://www.icann.org/en/public-comment/proceeding/proposed-top-level-domain-string-for-private-use-24-01-2024)

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has made a provisional
> determination that “.INTERNAL” should be reserved for private-use and
> internal network applications. Prior to review and approval of this
> reservation by the ICANN Board, we are seeking feedback on whether the
> selection complies with the specified procedure from SAC113, and any
> other observations that this string would be an inappropriate
> selection for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer according to [the IETF spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt) is:

```
.localhost
.test
.example
.invalid
```

I'm surprised at all the aggro answers, when real specific guidance has been there since 1999.

I cannot say if this will always bypass HSTS.  That may still be an open issue.

Comment: The `.test` is for testing only. Remaining are off-topic for this question.

Comment: `.localhost` TLD works only for the device. chrome will resolve all subdomain to `127.0.0.1` and `::1` without querying upstream dns server.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure this will help you, but for internal DNS inside my AWS account, I use `.aws` as the tld, and it seems to work perfectly fine.

I know there are some TLDs you should just flat out not use, but other than those, I don't think it's too strict.

I worked at a few larger companies, where they would use the authentication source as the TLD, meaning if it was a MS/Windows server, using Active Directory as the auth source, it would be `.ad`, and some others would be `.ldap` (Why they weren't just using the same source? or servers replicating from the same directory service? I don't know, it was like that when I got there)

Good luck

Comment: Amazon has now registered `.aws` as a TLD so you might start seeing problems eventually: http://nic.aws/

Comment: For information, the .aws is registered recently "25 March 2016" => http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings

Comment: While I don't think using a phony TLD is that big of a deal, at least not if the whole system is closed off and uses a proxy to communicate with the internet at large, ".aws" is a really bad choice unless you're NOT in AWS! There's way too many conceivable scenarios where you won't be able to communicate with AWS anymore.