# AD domain name selection

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing local versus public domain name for Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/71052/choosing-local-versus-public-domain-name-for-active-directory)

I'm using `company.com.qa` as my email domain, which I have hosted with my ISP. Can I use same domain name, `company.com.qa`, for my Windows 2008 Domain Controller? Should I use `company.local` or something else?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest `local.company.com.qa` if you're `company.com.qa`.  Using `company.local` will cause you problems if you have Mac clients on your network.

Comment: Could you expand on this, please?

Comment: Sure.  Macs use `.local` as an indicator that a name should be resolved via Bonjour, so they'll try that first.  In our case that means a 30 second wait to look up any `something.something.local` address that our AD serves up (we went with `companyname.local` before realizing this).  As well, if you want a Mac server, it will refuse to use a `.local` name for itself.  `corp.company.com.qa` or whatever is good as well.

Comment: Some people use domainname.corp for theirs. Really though, not much of a problem if you use your real domain name either if you can manage a separate dns for internal vs public. The only problem with this is the lack of http://domainname.com for internal people.

Comment: My honest opinion is that you should use a subdomain of your real domain: DNS will be sane (remember, you don't have to make that DNS public just because it's in a real domain!) and it just makes sense.  That's a subjective measure, obviously :)

Answer (score 4):

Conventional wisdom on this matter is to use a subdomain of an Internet-registered DNS name you already own. So in your case, something like **corp.company.com.qa** or **ad.company.com.qa**.