# How to configure DNS for internal domain resolution on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a Windows server with a private DNS server for the AD system named `office.example.com`. The public domain name `example.com` is managed by a hosting service and points to a public IP address. When I join a client to the `office.example.com` domain, the name is sometimes resolved to the correct private IP address and sometimes to the incorrect public IP address. This causes connectivity issues for clients inside the domain. How can I configure DNS to ensure that `office.example.com` always resolves to the private IP address?

**Update**

The last sentence is actually not what I intended to do.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/71052/choosing-local-versus-public-domain-name-for-active-directory) question was used as a guideline for my solution. My problem is, I am not sure how to apply the second suggested solution in reality:

> Subdomain of an existing public domain name which will never be used publicly (e.g. corp.mycompany.com).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure DNS to ensure that office.example.com always resolves to the private IP address?

By only using the internal private IP address of the DNS Server(s) on the clients. Never use public external DNS Server IP addresses for AD clients. That is a DNS worst practice and a security worst practice.

Comment: I understand that, I formulated it badly. What I want is, that if the client is inside the subnet of the AD it should resolve the private address.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new AD because we run into the same issues because of using “.nl” for our internal domain.

If you want to resolve this, you have to create an internal DNS zone for example.com and put all the records you’re using into that zone file.

If you however have a new domain setup it’s better to rename it to “.lan” or “.local” because those will

Comment: I saw the following question which I am trying to follow. It says that it is not recommended to use .local or similar. My question basically is, how can I recreate that.
https://serverfault.com/questions/71052/choosing-local-versus-public-domain-name-for-active-directory