# What should I name my Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows AD Domain naming recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations)

There are a lot of really screwed up configurations out there, because people didn't take a minute to sit down and think about something as simple as the name for their Active Directory forest. I'm asking this question to self-answer so that this knowledge can be more readily available. If you think you have a better answer, by all means add your input (but be prepared to defend it!)

So, what should I name my new Active Directory?

Comment: Hasn't this already been covered here a lot?  Dup: http://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-ad-domain-naming-recommendations http://serverfault.com/questions/71052/choosing-local-versus-public-domain-name-for-active-directory
Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-for-private-networks/17566 http://serverfault.com/questions/47087/using-local-for-internal-websites