# Active Directory Domain Names - Forest/Tree/Children

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, domain-name

I've been doing some reading on suggested top-level-domains for AD and whatnot.  I used to setup domains as `company.local` and that worked just fine, however, more people want to use their external domain `company.com` instead of the .local suffix.

I've got a quick clarification question, how am I supposed to set up my first forest if we're going to actually use our registered domain name?

It's easy enough to setup a new forest with `company.com` but wouldn't I then have to add a child-domain of `corp.company.com` to a new DC?  Essentially **requiring** two DCs just to set up the one domain.

Or would I create the first forest as `corp.company.com` and be done with it?  That seems to make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bingo on your last statement.

Set up your AD forest as corp.

corp.company.com.

Edit: Also read this post by MDMarra: [What should I name my Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/473529/what-should-i-name-my-active-directory)

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation/idea you're expressing isn't quite correct. The recommendation is not to use your publicly registered domain name as the name of your AD domain. The recommendation is to use a sub-domain of your publicly registered domain name. More specifically, the recommendation is to use a sub-domain that you do not plan to use in your public DNS namespace. Your example is a perfect example of how to do it.

Public namespace: company.com

AD namespace: corp.company.com

Comment: That's the difference that wasn't clicking to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...