# After DCPROMO, going to URL of website doesn't work (same as domain) due to DNS issue

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I just created the office PDC and its the same domain name as our actual website. The problem I am having is the DNS Server does not point traffic to the correct IP address. I've experienced this before and never had a work around so I really need help. The error is:

A delegation for this DNS server cannot be created because the authoritative parent zone cannot be found or it does not run Windows DNS server. If you are integrating with an existing DNS infrastructure, you should manually create a delegation to this DNS server in the parent zone to ensure reliable name resolution from outside the domain “something.com”. Otherwise, no action is required.

Windows Server 2008 R2 - This is a PDC, DNS was installed.

www.something.com and something.com both do not work....

Comment: There is no PDC in Active Directory

Answer (score 1):

The www records you can handle with an A record pointing to the external IP (or internal if hosted internally).  Evan is right about just the http://domain.com name though.

We've had arguments/discussions before about AD naming conventions and split-DNS infrastructures.  The consensus at this point is here:

[What should I name my Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/473529/what-should-i-name-my-active-directory)

Since you just created your AD, if at all possible I would highly recommend renaming it to something else following the practices above.

You can look at renaming it using these instructions:  http://www.techieshelp.com/how-to-rename-a-server-2008-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Same as this question [Sharing Domain name between domain controller and webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/38208/sharing-domain-name-between-domain-controller-and-webserver)

It's not going to work and shouldn't use the same name internally as the external name.