# Dns trouble: can't ping networkbox.local from other computers

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, internal-dns, bind

On my ubuntu dns server I use bind9 and this tutorial [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/dns-server-setup-using-bind-in-ubuntu.html) I have setup networkbox.local to 192.168.1.3.
When I ping this from my server it works correctly. But when I try and ping from another computer on the network It does not read the ipaddress. I have setup my other computer to use 192.168.1.3 (the dns server) as their default dns server. Using the tutorial they are able to ping other domains fine but not my local one :(

Comment: networkbox.local? You mean as in mDNS?

Answer (score 1):

It should work. On the "another computer", what does `dig networkbox.local` yield? The line SERVER, near the end, should tell you if the "another computer" indeed used your DNS server.

PS : ".local" [is a bad idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping your DNS server by IP [eg. `ping 192.168.1.3`]?

If so, then your resolver isn't working properly; Try `getent hosts networkbox.local`] and see if that returns the correct IP address...

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that your client use your DNS server ? do a 'host networkbox.local'. Is it correctly answered ? If not, there is a network configuration error (check IP, masks, firewalls... on both).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of firewall software running on your box? Maybe your server is intentionally not returning ping requests.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try:

```
dig a networkbox.local @192.168.1.3
```

from the client machine. This will tell you whether server is correctly configured.
If the answer is ok, you should start with checking /etc/resolv.conf, because problem seems to lie on client side.
Also you can see what's going on using tcpdump - don't forget this.