# How to use a local Leopard Server Mail server acting "like" an Exchange mail server

Tags: exchange, osx-snow-leopard

We have a local Exchange 2003 server (company ***.local***) who is collecting POP3 mail accounts on a distant (company ***.com***) mailserver.
The mails are collected by the Exchange server every 5-10 minutes and stored locally (on company ***.local***), so the users can read them without going on the "real" mail server (company.***com***)  What was explaned to me is that the mail collection is made with POP

Now we are migrating on Snow Leopard Server.

We have chosen to use a new extension for our local domain: ***.leo***
So our mailserver's FQDN is ***mail***.company.***leo***,  and the users have a ***user*** 1-2-3@company.***leo*** formated mail address.

**A)** All works fine except that I can't find ***how to tell*** the mail.company.leo that he must retreive the mails from the "real" public server (mail.company.com)
I'm hoping to use IMAP  and not POP.

I can send mail using SMTP relay from mail.company.leo but (I know it's trivial) answering is not possible, even if I specify the reply-to as user@company.com (this seems to be related to **A)** )

I don't know if it's very complicated (I suspect not, but...) to achieve what I want to do, and I'm not a genius.
But as I'm a little bit lost, I hopesomebody can or will help me.

Solving this will allow us to use iCal invitations too, so a lot of services depends of these mailserver settings

Some of you discuss the fact thta we choose to use a "new" tld with the .leo extension. We have no problem for that, we could use **.local**. no problem ;)

We used .leo instead of .local just to differentiate the two systems (Exchange and SnowLeopardServer). The question was not about that, it was just to know if we can set a SnowLeopard mail server to act like an Exchange Server.

Again thank you for your advice and help

Richard

Thanks in advance 
Richard

Comment: Yes, it's what I want to do. But **not** with Exchange.  
Exchange will be abandoned after we are sure we can do a sync (or at least a retrieve/fetch between mail.com and mail.leo

So I don't really understand what you mean with "...set up imapsync you enter the user in the form //"

"So if your domain is DOM [**mail.company.com** (?)], and the admin user is "admin" and the mail box you want to sync is "fred" then youd set the user in imapsync as DOM/admin/fred"

I will take y look to imapsync , if usable with Snow Leopard Server.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please do not [invent TLDs](http://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-for-private-networks/17566#17566).

Comment: why .leo? you do know it's not a TLD right? presumably because it's Snow Leopard right? What happens when you move to Lion or Bengal?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to syncronise mail for certain users between a src server mail.com and a target server, mail.leo.

If that is correct then you can use imapsync.
You can set up exchange to allow an admin user to authenitcate and access other users mailboxes.
you do this by granting access rights to the admin user.
Then when you set up imapsync you enter the user in the form
//

So if your domain is DOM, and the admin user is "admin" and the mail box you want to sync is "fred" then youd set the user in imapsync as DOM/admin/fred.