# CentOS BIND DNS Troubleshooting?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

I'm trying to setup my first BIND9 DNS server for a small local network and can't seem to get it working.  I want to create a 'local' domain of max.app

As far as I can tell named is running, but it doesn't seem to be serving my domain records?

```
service named start
```

Returns OK, and the demon is running on boot.

If I try and ping mac1 I get: unknown host mac1

If I try and ping mac1.max.app I get: unknown host mac1

When I try nslookup I get:

```
nslookup max.app
Server: 8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   max.app
Address: 67.192.47.244
```

As you can see I'm not serving records from my local bind service (192.168.100.10)

**My /etc/resolv.conf file looks like this:**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search max.app
nameserver 192.168.100.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**My /etc/named.conf file looks like this:**

```
acl local-network { 192.168.100.0/24;  }; 

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.100.10; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { local-network;  };
    recursion yes;

    query-source address * port 53;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
};


logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};


zone "max.app" IN {   
    type master;   
    file "max.app.zone";   
    allow-update { none; }; 
};

zone "100.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;   
    file "max.app.rr.zone";   
    allow-update { none; }; 
};
```

**My /var/named/max.app.zone file looks like this:**

```
$ORIGIN max.app. 
$TTL 86400 
@   IN  SOA dns1.max.app.   email.gmail.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial                     
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                     
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
            604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day  


    IN  NS  dns1.max.app.   

dns1    IN  A   192.168.100.10
CentOS1 IN  A   192.168.100.15
CentOS2 IN  A   192.168.100.25

mac1    IN  A   192.168.100.50
mac2    IN  A   192.168.100.55
mac3    IN  A   192.168.100.60

www     IN  CNAME   CentOS1
```

**My /var/named/max.app.rr.zone file looks like this:**

```
$ORIGIN 100.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 
$TTL 86400 
@   IN  SOA dns1.max.app.   email.gmail.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial                     
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                     
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
            604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day           

    IN  NS  dns1.max.app.

10  IN  PTR dns1.max.app.
15  IN  PTR CentOS1.max.app.
20  IN  PTR CentOS2.max.app.

50  IN  PTR mac1.max.app.
55  IN  PTR mac1.max.app.
60  IN  PTR mac1.max.app.
```

**Service named status returns:**

```
version: 9.7.0-P2-RedHat-9.7.0-5.P2.el6_0.1
CPUs found: 2
worker threads: 2
number of zones: 15
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is OFF
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
named (pid  1121) is running.
```

This "number of zones: 15" seems a bit odd?  When I only have 1 zone defined in named.conf

**UPDATE 7/14 5:45PM CST**

Ok I've followed the suggestions below but things still don't seem to want to work.

Added to /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

**dig @192.168.100.10 mac1.max.app a** returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @192.168.100.10 mac1.max.app a
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48036
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mac1.max.app.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mac1.max.app.   86400   IN  A   192.168.100.15

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
max.app.        86400   IN  NS  dns1.max.app.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns1.max.app.       86400   IN  A   192.168.100.10

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.100.10#53(192.168.100.10)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 14 17:30:53 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85
```

**dig @192.168.100.10 mac1.max.app ns returns**

> ; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @192.168.100.10 mac1.max.app ns ; (1
>   server found) ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<-
>   opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28099 ;; flags: qr aa rd ra;
>   QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;mac1.max.app.       IN  NS
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: max.app.        86400   IN  SOA dns1.max.app.
>   email.gmail.com. 2001062501 21600 3600 604800 86400
>
> ;; Query time: 8 msec ;; SERVER: 192.168.100.10#53(192.168.100.10) ;;
>   WHEN: Thu Jul 14 17:18:23 2011 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 94

nslookup show that named is listing on port 53

```
tcp   0   0 dns1:53                    *:*   LISTEN   2880/named
tcp   0   0 localhost.localdomain:53   *:*   LISTEN   2880/named
```

Comment: Are you doing the pinging from the nameserver, or from some other machine? I would try adding the following to your resolv.conf: nameserver localhost

Comment: Ya I'm on the DNS box.  I tried swapping out the IP address for localhost in the resolv.conf file... no luck.

Comment: Don't hijack other people's domains; it's causing you problems now, and it'll only cause further hassle in the future.

Comment: @womble how is it causing problems now?  I really don't think that has anything to do with the current problem. Its on a local network that myself and one other dude use, hijacking is a bit harsh.

Comment: Well, you already can't be sure that the answers you're getting are your own; down the line, if you want to access the legitimate `max.com` you'll be SOL.  There are already domains available specifically for this purpose (`.local`).  "Hijacking" is the correct term for what you're doing.

Comment: sorry to throw in a 'me too', but womble is correct. it's simply bad practice to use a domain for which you do not have proper authority. use max.local - or max.coom, or max.comm or max.company, or max.nickfaraday or max.x or whatever suits your fancy. there simply is no valid reason to use someone else's domain for this experiment. as has been confirmed by the courts, a domain name is tangible, fungible *property*. regardless of your intentions (which make no mistake, i presume to be good), you're using someone else's property without authority if you use max.com. and besides all that, as wom

Comment: Fair enough... I've changed the TDL to .app and have made the changes to the question above. So now the domain reads [max.app] same issue persists.

Comment: That is not the `dig` command that `Cakemox` specified.

Comment: Just because .app doesn't conflict with an assigned TLD now, don't mean that it never will (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain). Also .local is defined for use with multicast DNS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local). There is currently no TLD reserved for private use. See https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network and use your own real domain.

Comment: ". I've changed the TDL to .app" Not a good idea. `.app` is now in IANA root, handled by Google. So it is a live **TLD**. Don't hijack any random string and expect it it will remain unique. This probably has an easy solution: use designated TLDs (`.example`, `.test`, `.invalid`) for tests and for live do this: create a domain, anyone in any TLD, so it exists, and use it as suffix of all your internal needs. This is futureproof.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to use bind as both recursive and authoritative at the same time. You will suffer endless stream of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

Remove the two google nameservers from your `resolv.conf`.  Your nameserver is failing, but you're not getting much useful information because nslookup is falling through to the next nameserver.

Use `dig` instead if `nslookup`.  The status response from dig is helpful in troubleshooting.

```
dig @192.168.100.10 mac1.max.app. a
dig @192.168.100.10 max.app. ns
```

Make sure you check your logs to see if your zone is actually loading.

Check netstat to make sure named is listening on port 53 of the appropriate interface.

Comment: updated the question.  I added the dig results / verified that named is listening on port 53

Answer (score 0):

Your named is configured to listen on `127.0.0.1` and `::1` but your hosts resolve.conf says to ask on `192.168.100.10` try changing your listen-on directive to

```
listen-on {
    127.0.0.1;
    192.168.100.10;
    };
```

Also check that your firewall is allowing connections on port 53. I have the following lines in my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` to do this

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: updated the questions.  added the listen-on IP and the Firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Even if far after the battle, my tips for troubleshooting things like that are quite simple:

- use `named-checkzone` to double check validity of your zonefile(s)
- use `named-checkconf` to double check validity of your bind configuration file
- increase logging in it
- do queries with `dig` + `@` flag to direct traffic precisely to the server, and assess the replies plus what happens in the logfiles.

But in short the MAJOR things **NOT TO DO** (so to stop doing before even trying to solve problems):

- hijack any currently existing or random name/TLD and pretend it will never create collision; this is wrong way to see the problem
- use same bind as both authoritative and recursive

As for this specific case, the `dig` given at the end is PERFECTLY normal and EXACTLY what expected.

The request was "mac1.max.app ns" (note the record type of "ns" being asked) towards a nameserver that ought to be authoritative on zone `max.app`.

Since that name `mac1.max.app` does NOT have `NS` records, but only one `A` record, the nameserver has to answer:

- with a return code of `NOERROR` because the name exists
- with no content in `ANSWER` section because, indeed, there are no `NS` records for `mac1.max.app`
- but since it is authoritative on `max.app`, it gives in  `AUTHORITATIVE` section the `SOA` record of the zone in which the record is, which is indeed `max.app`.

It is easy to reproduce the same thing with any given name, let us try with `www.nic.app` (showing the danger as outlined in comments above to use any arbitrary name, as `.app` was awarded to Google and hence is now a completely valid and public TLD) which certainly should have `A` record and others but no `NS` records (things would be different if the name has a `CNAME` record)

1. Authoritative nameservers for `nic.app`:

```
$ dig NS nic.app +short
ns2.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns3.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
```

2. Asking any of them for our query:

```
$ dig NS www.nic.app @ns3.google.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.18.4 <<>> NS www.nic.app @ns3.google.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 355
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 198fd01a7c794358
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.nic.app.       IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 52

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 355
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.nic.app.       IN NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nic.app.        1m IN SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. (
                463794447  ; serial
                900        ; refresh (15 minutes)
                900        ; retry (15 minutes)
                1800       ; expire (30 minutes)
                60         ; minimum (1 minute)
                )

;; Query time: 54 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.36.10#53(ns3.google.com.) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 29 17:32:06 EST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

As expected, and per design of the DNS protocol:

- `NOERROR` return code, as the name exist, but not that type
- hence no content in `ANSWER` section as no `NS` records on that name
- but `SOA` record in `AUTHORITY` section to show the "start" (highest level/closest to root) of the zone in which the record we query for exists

As such there is really nothing to troubleshoot in this question, things are working as designed, if not as expected, but to answer that there would need more details on the expectations.
Or just trying queries for the `A` record type and not the `NS` one.