# message of "enter at least one recipient" on roundcube, when i have my mail server ok

Tags: domain-name-system, roundcube, thunderbird

I recently installed roundcube and tried to use it, I have a web server (were I have that roundcube) and a mail server, with thunderbird in my client machine, I can use all mail users I made witouth problems, I can send and receive emails if i use thunderbird, but  no with roundcube

Even when i can log in roundcube with a user without problems, and even receive mails send for him, i cant send any email from that user, I just receive the next message "enter at least one recipient" when i try to do it, like if i didnt specified any receiver, the receiver is a user of the same domain and i can log in roundcube with that user too, so i dont get why cant send messages to it

So anyone knows or have any idea of what could be the problem here?, maybe the dns or something? i tought it could be a bad configured dns, but isnt strange since i can send and receive mails with thunderbird? i can even receive mails and log with roundcube, i dont have any idea of what to do

EDIT:

on the server mail i have three virtual domains (domain1.al1,domain2.al1, and final.fi1), each one has some users, and as i said every user works fine with thunderbird, the user with im trying to send the mail is userf@final.fi1, to the user user1@domain1.al1

Comment: I suspect there is something unusual about your mail (character that should be escaped but was not, malformed IDN, no FQDN). Might be easier to figure out of you share what exactly you entered into the `To` field.

Comment: @anx i already edited this post, dont know if this information is usefull or not, but i hope it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is caused by the Arabic numerals in the last label.**

> three virtual domains domain1.al**1**,domain2.al**1**, and final.fi**1**

*Roundcube* performs some preliminary validation on entered emails, throwing out domains where the last label contains numbers.

In ICANN maintained TLDs such would only occur in *IDN* form, such as `.xn--p1ai` representing `.рф`.

The purpose of rejecting some possibly-invalid domains is usually preventing unintended parsing of a recipient name as a recipient address (or vice versa).

There is a [simple change scheduled](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/5588) for a future release that relaxes the domain validation so it would match your unusual domains as well.

You would still be well advised to only use domains that are [guaranteed not to be assigned to a third party](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network) eventually. That is, a subdomain of a domain you own (or at the very least, a domain reserved for such purposes).

Comment: thanks you very much!
i will try using that modification and see if this works